# .htaccess redirect rule for subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My site has a lot of subdomains(3rd and 4th levels), for example:

```
http://de.site.com/catalog
http://product.de.site.com
```

and I need to automaticaly redirect all domains with "www", for example

```
http://www.de.site.com/catalog
http://www.product.de.site.com
```

to url without "www":

```
http://de.site.com/catalog
http://product.de.site.com
```

Could you please help me with .htaccess rules for this case ? Please note that this rule must be applied only for 3rd+ levels of domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks, it works for all level of the domains. But I need to save my previous rule for the 2rd level domain with "www" - RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] How it could be achieved?

Comment: now it works fine for 2rd level, but  "www" is still accessible for 3rd+ levels of the domains, for example www.de.examle.com