# .htaccess redirect rule for language subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In additional to htaccess rules from my previous post -[.htaccess redirect rule for subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971086/htaccess-redirect-rule-for-subdomains)
I need to add rule fo "en" subdomain.

For example I have following url structures:

```
en.example.com
someword.en.example.com

it.example.com
someword.it.example.com
```

where "en" and "it" is a language definition. "en" is a default language on the site, so I'd like to automaticaly redirect all requests that contain "en" in domains to domains without "en", for example:

```
en.example.com -> example.com
someword.en.example.com > someword.example.com
```

but all other languages should remain in url. I need it only for "en".

Could you please help me with .htaccess rule for this case ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.en\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```